# Get the "CURL" operation from each Rest Assured test and print in the console when not pass the test

Tags: java, rest, curl, testing, rest-assured

I need Get the "CURL" operation from each Rest Assured test and print in the console when not pass the test. It's possible?

For axample, convert:

```
 given().relaxedHTTPSValidation().
   auth().basic("name", "password").
   param("grant_type","client_credentials").
 when().
   post("https://test_url/oauth/token").
 then().
   statusCode(200);
```

to

```
curl --user name:passwoed -k -X POST \
https://test_url/oauth/token \
-H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
-H 'content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
-d grant_type=client_credentials
```

Comment: Not something that I have tried, but the details in the link are quite similar to your ask - https://github.com/dzieciou/curl-logger

Answer (score 9):

Include the following dependencies.

Maven:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.github.dzieciou.testing</groupId>
  <artifactId>curl-logger</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.4</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.6</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
    <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.9</version>
</dependency>
```

Once configured use the following piece of code to log the curl request in the console output.

```
package com.api.test;

import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.is;

import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import com.sample.model.EnrollEmail;
import com.github.dzieciou.testing.curl.CurlLoggingRestAssuredConfigFactory;

import io.restassured.RestAssured;
import io.restassured.config.RestAssuredConfig;
import io.restassured.http.ContentType;
import io.restassured.path.json.JsonPath;
import io.restassured.response.Response;
import io.restassured.response.ValidatableResponse;

/**
 * @author vamsiravi
 *
 */
public class Sample {

    @Test(enabled=true)
    public void sampleAPITest() {

        RestAssuredConfig config = CurlLoggingRestAssuredConfigFactory.createConfig();  

        EnrollEmail email = new EnrollEmail();
        email.setEmailAddress("sample@domain.com");
        RestAssured.given().config(config).contentType(ContentType.JSON).body(email).when().post("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts").then()
        .assertThat()
        .statusCode(201);   

    }
}
```

Output :

```
[main] DEBUG curl - **
curl 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts' 
-H 'Accept: */*' 
-H 'Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8' 
-H 'Host: jsonplaceholder.typicode.com' 
-H 'Connection: Keep-Alive' 
-H 'User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.3 (Java/1.8.0_181)' 
--data-binary '{"emailAddress":"sample@domain.com"}' 
--compressed 
-k 
-v**

PASSED: sampleAPITest
```

Answer (score 5):

Based of [@vamsi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55461288/6654475) this is the full implementation of what worked for us.

POM

```
<http.client.version>4.5.3</http.client.version>
<curl.logger.version>1.0.5</curl.logger.version>

<dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
   <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
   <version>${http.client.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.github.dzieciou.testing</groupId>
   <artifactId>curl-logger</artifactId>
   <version>${curl.logger.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

And

```
public class Requests {
    public String baseUrl;
    public RequestSpecification getRequestSpecification(String authorizationToken) {
        /** Enables printing request as curl under the terminal as per https://github.com/dzieciou/curl-logger */
        Options options = Options.builder()
                .printMultiliner()
                .updateCurl(curl -> curl
                        .removeHeader("Host")
                        .removeHeader("User-Agent")
                        .removeHeader("Connection"))
                .build();
        RestAssuredConfig config = CurlLoggingRestAssuredConfigFactory.createConfig(options);
        baseUrl = Constants.getEndpoint();
        RestAssured.baseURI = baseUrl;
        RequestSpecification rq = given()
                .config(config)
                .contentType(ContentType.JSON)
                .contentType("application/json\r\n")
                .header("Accept", "application/json").and()
                .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
                .header("Authorization", authorizationToken)
                .when()
                .log()
                .everything();
        return rq;
    }
}
```

Generates this bit on the run terminal:

[image]

If you can't see it straight away on your run terminal after triggering your tests, or if needing to log it to the standard system output or to a .log file, creating a logback.xml file under the test/resources folder as per the below may help you.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>

<appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%-4relative [%thread] %-5level %logger{35} - %msg %n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>

<appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
    <file>mylog.log</file>
    <append>true</append>
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%-5level] %logger{15} - %msg%n%rEx</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>

<logger name="curl" level="DEBUG">
    <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
</logger>
```

PS: Changing between the system output or .log file is done based on which one you pass as a reference for the "curl" logger appender.

[image]

Comment: Great description, although it lacks some crucial components. Those are slf4j-api and logback-classic dependencies. Without them, the solution didn't work for me.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, you're right. These are also needed.

Answer (score 4):

An alternative is to parse the output of the `log().all()` [as seen in my article](https://www.jvt.me/posts/2020/05/18/rest-assured-curl/).

Note: I've not shared the code here, as it's Apache 2.0 licensed, which is different to [Stack Overflow's default licensing](https://stackoverflow.com/help/licensing).